# How to delete particular line from a textfile in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How to delete particular line from a textfile in Ruby on Rails?

Example :

```
1: CLEAR                  ,  "Clear"
2: APPROACH_DIVERGING     ,  "Approach Diverging"
3: ADVANCE_APPROACH       ,  "Advance Approach"
4: APPROACH_RESTRICTED    ,  "Approach Restricted""
5: APPROACH2              ,  "Approach"
```

From above example I want to the delete 3rd line.

```
3: ADVANCE_APPROACH       ,  "Advance Approach"
```

Finally, it will display like this:

```
CLEAR                  ,  "Clear"
APPROACH_DIVERGING     ,  "Approach Diverging"
APPROACH_RESTRICTED    ,  "Approach Restricted""
APPROACH2              ,  "Approach"
```

Comment: can you be clearer as to how you identify which line is to be deleted? Is it always line 3, or does it always match a particular regex, or whatever?

Comment: dynamically i am going to get the line values... from that one need to delete particular line... line number will vary

Answer (score 4):

You could read all the lines into an array, then write them back to the file while omitting the lines you don't want. (This code only searches for the specific line you mentioned, but you could build a regular expression to compare to `line` instead).

```
lines = File.readlines(filename)
File.open(filename, "w") do |f|
  lines.each { |line| f.puts(line) unless line == "ADVANCE_APPROACH       ,  \"Advance Approach\"") }
end
```